# Fetching ID for same name

Tags: java, eclipse

I have data in below format -

| Name | ID | new_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | null |
| John | 2 | null |

I am updating new_ID column where name='John' and it is updating with the 2nd ID in both rows like below -

| Name | ID | new_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 2 |
| John | 2 | 2 |

I want the new_id column to be updated with correct ID that is '1' for first row and '2' for second row.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't update the DB.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: I have made the changes can you please try

Comment: But it will update it with same ID.. my issue is I need to update the new_id column with correct ID and not same ID twice

Comment: Please show your actual code. There is no `updateRow` method with that signature, and no class named `Resultset`.

Comment: Take a look at the example of updating a column value in the API: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rest.updateRow("new_id",rest.getString("ID"))
```

Comment: It is updating same ID in both the columns

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).